# Jinja lookup key in for loop

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I pass 2 groups of data from my view.py to my html file.
But only one group of data is shown in the webpage.

html:

```
<h3>Database: A</h3>
           <table>
              <tr>
                  <th>A</th>
                  <th>Counts A-1</th>
                  <th>Counts A-2</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
              </tr>
              {% load lookup %}
              {% for i in Amatch %}
             <tr>
                 <th> {{ Amatch|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </th>
                 <td> {{ Amatchtotal|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
                 <td> {{ AmatchCount|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
                 <td> {{ Avalue|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
             </tr>
             {% endfor %}
          </table>

    <h3>Database: B</h3>
          <table>
             <tr>
                 <th>B</th>
                 <th>Counts B-1</th>
                 <th>Counts B-2</th>
                 <th>Value</th>
             </tr>
            {% load lookup %}
            {% for i in Bmatch %}
            <tr>
                <th> {{ Bmatch|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </th>
                <td> {{ Bmatchtotal|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
                <td> {{ BmatchCount|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
                <td> {{ Bvalue|lookup:forloop.counter0 }} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </table>
```

view.py

```
return render(request, 'analysis/result.html', {'Amatch':Amatch, 'Amatchtotal':Amatchtotal, 'AmatchCount':AmatchCount, 'A_re':A_re, 'Avalue':Avalue, 'Bmatch':Bmatch, 'Bmatchtotal':Bmatchtotal, 'BmatchCount':BmatchCount, 'B_re':B_re, 'Bvalue':Bvalue,})
```

Two groups of data are supposed to be shown on the page as I expected.
However, only the data from group B is shown on the page.
I tried to switch the order of group A and group B, but still only group B is shown.

I'm pretty sure data are passed successfully by checking them in terminal.

Are there anything wrong with my code?